# Rebuild Lazarus failed after ZEOS database lib installation

Tags: delphi, lazarus, zeos

Try to install ZEOS database components, but I failed at the install step:
Error message:

```
PPU Loading C:\ProgramData\lazarus\ideintf\units\x86_64-win64\win32\componenttreeview.ppu
PPU Source: componenttreeview.pas not found
PPU Source: C:\ProgramData\lazarus\images\componenttreeview.lrs time 2009/12/05 19:56:40 * componenttreeview.pas(156,31) Fatal: Can not find ComponentTreeView used by ObjectInspector, ppu=..\ideintf\units\x86_64-win64\win32\componenttreeview.ppu, package IDEIntf
```

What did I miss to install to get also componenttreeview and other missing stuff ?

Comment: I installed Zeos on a previous version of Lazarus and don't remember having any problem regarding that. Did you follow the instructions at http://wiki.freepascal.org/Zeos_tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have old files (of earlier installation tries?) laying around. Using a clean Lazarus checkout might help.